# Hola, tengo que poner el icono de instagram al lado del texto "instagram" pero intento y nada me lo mueve, alguno sabe que pasa? Gracias

Tags: html, css, position

[image: Ahi se ve el logo a la izquierda y necesito ponerlo al lado de la palabra instagram. Intente con la herramienta bottom, position, etc y nada me funciona.]

```
            <div class="row align-items-start ">
                
                <div class="col">
                Instagram
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-end">
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                One of three columns
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    </footer>
```

......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Edita la pregunta incluyendo todas las definiciones de los estilos que estás utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

si necesitas colocar la imagen del icono te falta abrir un div/img y despues si queres anclar algun link con (a). No se si esa era tu consulta, espero haberte ayudado saludos

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del div del col, intenta con esto, puedes cambiar el svg por una imagen o icono.

Omite el llamado al bootstrap.min.css.

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row align-items-start ">

  <div class="col">
    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center text-decoration-none" href="https://www.instagram.com/neoxsaibot/">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-instagram" style="margin-right: 5px;" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z" />
      </svg>
      <span>Instagram</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-end">
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    One of three columns
  </div>
</div>
```